# Bootstrap 4 grid system div disappears on collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys I'm trying to make bootstrap grid system with multiple rows in each other and it works fine until it collapses to mobile size. When it's collapsed for mobile one of my divs disappears.It basically becomes part of my larger div on right side of screen. The problem starts below `768px screen size`.Here is the code: 
HTML:

```
<section id="changeImageHover" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="container-fluid topLayer changeImageOne">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/716/400" alt="white image">
    <h3>wwwwwwwwwwwwww</h3>
    <p>asdasdasdsadasd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottomLayer">
    <div class="col-md-6 changeImageTwo">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/358/400" alt="mouth">
      <span>asdddddddddd</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 changeImageThree">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/358/400" alt="blue image">
      <h3>asdasdasd</h3>
      <p>asdasdasdsad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-5">
  <img id="changeThisImage" src="https://placebear.com/511/800" alt="girl pink background">
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

My second col-md-6 is the one that disappears. It has class `changeImageThree`.
SCSS:

```
#changeImageHover {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    .row {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        .col-md-7{
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 800px;
            img {
                height: 400px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            h3 {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 25px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left:19.5%;
                transform: translate(-19.5%,-50%);
            }
            p {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 56%;
                left:35%;
                transform: translate(-35%,-60%);
            }
            .container-fluid {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .changeImageThree {
                height: 400px;
            }
            .col-md-6 {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                h3 {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 38%;
                    transform: translate(-38%,-50%);
                }
                p {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 56%;
                    left:19%;
                    transform: translate(-17%,-50%);
                }
                span {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 54%;
                    left:36%;
                    transform: translate(-36%,-54%);
                }
            }
        }
        .col-md-5 {
            height: 800px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            img {
                height: 800px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the codepen so you can better understand my problem https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/LWNLzN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of the `height: 800px` on the `col-md-7`.

Also, the code is not using Bootstrap grid properly. For example, the immediate children of the `col-md-7` should be a single `row` with a `col-md-12`, and the 2 `col-md-6` below instead of the `container-fluid`.

Updated: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWZMVj

Comment: Thank you very much that worked great. One more question p-0, means padding 0 ? and using m-0 would this set margin to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your div disappears because you are using `col-md-6 only`. for responsiveness in small devices use `col-xs-*`

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
       <style type="text/css">
   #changeImageHover {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    .row {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        .col-md-7{
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 800px;
            img {
                height: 400px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            h3 {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 25px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left:19.5%;
                transform: translate(-19.5%,-50%);
            }
            p {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 14px;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 56%;
                left:35%;
                transform: translate(-35%,-60%);
            }
            .container-fluid {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .changeImageThree {
                height: 400px;
            }
            .col-md-6 {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                h3 {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 38%;
                    transform: translate(-38%,-50%);
                }
                p {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 56%;
                    left:19%;
                    transform: translate(-17%,-50%);
                }
                span {
                    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 54%;
                    left:36%;
                    transform: translate(-36%,-54%);
                }
            }
        }
        .col-md-5 {
            height: 800px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            img {
                height: 800px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <section id="changeImageHover" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-7">
  <div class="container-fluid topLayer changeImageOne">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/716/400" alt="white image">
    <h3>wwwwwwwwwwwwww</h3>
    <p>asdasdasdsadasd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottomLayer">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 changeImageTwo">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/358/400" alt="mouth">
      <span>asdddddddddd</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 changeImageThree">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/358/400" alt="blue image">
      <h3>asdasdasd</h3>
      <p>asdasdasdsad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-5">
  <img id="changeThisImage" src="https://placebear.com/511/800" alt="girl pink background">
 </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've already tried that col-sm-6 col-xs-6 but neither has worked I've updated codepen https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/LWNLzN you can check it.